# Turtle Graphics-OnClick 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python, button, turtle-graphics

I am making a calculator with turtle-graphics. I want the turtle to type something when I press a button. The code is below:

```py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("rob it")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=500, height=600)

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
FONT_SIZE = 12
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')


button = turtle.Turtle()
button.hideturtle()
button.shape('circle')
button.fillcolor('red')
button.penup()
button.goto(150, 650)
button.write("Click me!", align='center', font='arial') 
button.sety(150 +  + FONT_SIZE)
button.onclick('type_0')
button.showturtle()
#I think that's where the error occurs

def type_0(x, y):
    turtle.penup
    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.goto(150, 650)

    turtle.pendown
    turtle.write('hello!', font='arial', align='center')
    turtle.hideturtle


while True:
    wn.update()
```

But I am getting this error. I have tried everything and I cannot fix it. Any solutions? For some reason I am not able to call the type_0 function.
So I am typing this because I don't know what other details to add and I am new to python so I will appreciate any comment or help.

Comment: The `.onclick()` method wants *the actual function to be called* (`type_0`), NOT a string containing the name of that function (`'type_0'`).  You will need to move the function definition up above this line, so that the name is actually defined.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an implementation which will work but not an optimal/elegant solution. Okay to start with. As you learn more you can make your code much more elegant. One of the way is to use a class with methods. Also, please note that x,y arguments are not used in your function.

```py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("rob it")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=500, height=600)

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
FONT_SIZE = 12
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')


button = turtle.Turtle()
button.hideturtle()
button.shape('circle')
button.fillcolor('red')
button.penup()
button.goto(150, 650)
button.write("Click me!", align='center', font='arial') 
button.sety(150 +  + FONT_SIZE)

def type_0(x, y,turtle_in_fn=button ):
    turtle_in_fn.penup
    turtle_in_fn.color('white')
    turtle_in_fn.goto(150, 150)

    turtle_in_fn.pendown
    turtle_in_fn.write('hello!', font='arial', align='center')
    turtle_in_fn.hideturtle

# Note that type_0 is a function. type_0 should not be within single quotes ''
button.onclick(type_0) 
button.showturtle()


while True:
    wn.update()
```